# Tabulator does not execute script in ajax-load cell data

Tags: javascript, tabulator

Not sure if this is a bug or ignorance.

I have a `Tabluator` table loading data from ajax:

```
    productsTable = new Tabulator("#productsTable", {
      height:"100%",
      layout:"fitColumns",
      ajaxURL: dataSource,
      columns: [
        {title: "Orders",     field: "orders_test_col", formatter: "html", headerSort: false, headerHozAlign: "center", hozAlign: "center", headerSort:false, width: "25%"},
      ]
    });
```

The data I am returning looks like this:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "itemId": 2896652,
            "orders_test_col": "\u003cscript\u003econsole.log('orders_test_col: 2896652')\u003c/script\u003e",
        }
    ]
}
```

Essentially `<script>console.log('orders_test_col: 4097380')</script>`

How can I get this script to run after loading in the data? In the Tabulator [docs](https://tabulator.info/docs/5.4/format#format-builtin) they explicitly talk about `beware of script injection` so I assume(d) that it should run that data.

Answer (score 0):

You should **NEVER** include/execute scripts included in ajax data it is extremely bad practice and majorly insecure.

You should restructure your code so that you have defined the console log in the browser side code and the contents of the message is stored in the table data.

you could then trigger the console log on a `data-loaded` event

Comment: I perhaps agree with you, except, Datatables DOES execute the Javascript, so this is making our migration from Datatables to Tabulator very difficult.

Comment: You can add a custom formatter that doesn't escape the tags if you want to. That would enable it to work if you must. But if you are in the process of migrating I would strongly suggest improving your security posture in the process

Comment: What I actually ended up doing was writing something that went through and ran the script elements on a column of my choosing. That seemed to emulate pretty well what I was getting from Datatables. Maybe in the future we will switch to returning the data and generating everything browser side.